# Custom Keyboard In-App in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

Simple question: Is there a way to customize keyboards in Swift?

What i want: A keyboard with 0-9, delete, comma and +/- buttons

Default Keyboards are either missing the comma or comma and +/- buttons

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, you can create your own [`input view`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView) for a `UITextField`, but you will have to create the view and keys yourself.

Comment: Thats one way i also thought of. Are you sure that there is no other way of achieving this?

Comment: Check this tutorial. http://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the link, seems kind of useable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your best approach is to take the Decimal Keyboard as it is, and add the few additional functionality you need with an accessoryView. With this you can design a new row on top of the keyboard

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! THANKS